# iOS Core Data binary operation in predicate expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

This seems to be the same as [How to use binary flags in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716734/how-to-use-binary-flags-in-core-data) but I am getting an "Unsupported function expression" when trying.

I want to create a predicate that can find entities in my Core Data object store which have a certain ID and for which certain binary flags are not set.   This is my code snippet:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ownerID = %@ AND ((banned & 8) == 0)", THEUSERUSERID];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [PCDUser MR_requestAllWithPredicate:predicate];

_frController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[COMMDBMANAGER magicalRecordStack] context] sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKeyPath cacheName:nil];

[_frController setDelegate:self];
[_frController performFetch:&error];
```

Looking at the previous issue in the link above, it appears this should work.  However, I get a

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression banned & 8'
```

Because I need the `NSFetchedResultsController` results set  (and indexPaths etc) to include the filtered results, I have not been able to find a way to filter them after the fact and have the results set include that filtering.

How does one use binary flags in Core Data?

Comment: I had a similar predicate in `NSFetchRequest` and it worked. Are you sure that property `banned` exists and has a type that supports bitwise operations (for example, `Integer32`)?

Comment: Thank you.  I had been helping a node.js guy on the backend mysql database that supports this app (and which this CD store in the DB derives data from) and I had in my head the wrong name for the property.  In the CD schema I have `bannedFlags` but in mysql `banned` [don't ask why as I don't know] and after a long long weekend of dealing with `banned` I had a brain fart this morning.  Thanks for the reminder to double check the obvious.  Make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar predicate in `NSFetchRequest` and it worked. Check that property `banned` exists in your model and has a type that supports bitwise operations (for example, `Integer32`).